# Doctrine - ManyToMany relationship not deleting correctly

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Many to Many relationship between two entities using a link table. My problem is that on delete, it appears that the other entity, which should not be deleted, is trying to be deleted, rather than the row in the link table.

I have the following tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE `hotel_property` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`location_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`tier_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`description` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `hotel_amenity` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`value_str` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

And link table:

```
CREATE TABLE `hotel_property_amenity` (
`property_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`amenity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`property_id`,`amenity_id`),
KEY `IDX_197E8A3E549213EC` (`property_id`),
KEY `IDX_197E8A3E9F9F1305` (`amenity_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_197E8A3E9F9F1305` FOREIGN KEY (`amenity_id`) REFERENCES `hotel_amenity` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_197E8A3E549213EC` FOREIGN KEY (`property_id`) REFERENCES `hotel_property` (`id`)
)
```

So, I'm trying to delete a Property, which should also delete the hotel_property_amenity but my logs are showing the hotel_amenity is being deleted (or it's trying but it throws a constraint violation obviously)

Logs:

```
500 An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM hotel_amenity WHERE id = ?' with params [67]
```

.
.

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`hotel_property_amenity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_197E8A3E9F9F1305` FOREIGN KEY (`amenity_id`) REFERENCES `hotel_amenity` (`id`))
```

Doctrine Property Entity (where I think I may be wrong):

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(
 *        targetEntity="Test\Hotel\Entity\Amenity",
 *        indexBy="type",
 *        orphanRemoval=true,
 *        fetch="EXTRA_LAZY",
 *        cascade={"persist", "refresh", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="hotel_property_amenity",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="property_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="amenity_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
 *
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"featured" = "DESC", "sortPosition" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $amenities;
```

Does anyone have any idea where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem ended up being the cascade="remove". Once that is removed, the row in the bridge table is taken care of and the associated entity is left alone.